# CSS selector: no <img> as child

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to select all anchor tags that link to external sites that do not have child image tags. If I have an image as a link, it adds the little external link icon next to those images as well, but I don't want that.

This is what I have so far:

```
a[href^="http://"]{
  background:transparent url(..icon/external.png) center right no-repeat;
  display:inline-block;
  padding-right:18px;
}
```

As an added bonus, how would I make it work with "https://" links as well?

Comment: That can't currently be done with CSS. [There's still no parent selector.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: I can't wait for the CSS 4 spec to become standard... seems like there's a ton of cool features to come from there.

Comment: The padding gives space for the icon on the right side of the link, then the background adds the image itself, aligned to the right. inline-block makes the entire link including the image clickable. [See here for more info](http://web-kreation.com/all/add-file-type-icons-next-to-your-links-with-css/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isnt possible with plain CSS. However you could use a bit of jQuery wizardry:

jQuery:

```
$("a[href^='http://']:not(:has(img))").addClass("external");
```

CSS:

```
a.external {
  background:transparent url(..icon/external.png) center right no-repeat;
  display:inline-block;
  padding-right:18px;
}
```

See Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hKTBp/

See Demo (including HTTPS): http://jsfiddle.net/hKTBp/1/

Comment: I don't think you can safely assume he has jQuery installed.

Comment: @kojiro I agree, but I can safely say that what the OP wants isn't possible, and I've provided a neat alternative.

Comment: Nice fix! I would've preferred a non-JS solution, but this works. I do have jQuery, so this is fine.

Comment: Actually, how could I also make this match "https://" as well? I'm not sure how to do an AND case with jQuery.

Comment: `$("a[href^='http://']:not(:has(img)),a[href^='https://']:not(:has(img))")` or `$("a[href^='http://'],a[href^='https://']").not(":has(img)")`

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't sure if there was something like `href^='http://' && href^='https://'`, which would be nice to have.

Comment: @MaxGhost I'm not sure, so I've posted a question :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11887602/jquery-attribute-selector-x-y-or-x-z